# jQuery - Wait for this element and then execute 1 time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to manipluate the text in the slider.
But the problem is it only works with the first visible slide.

I need a method to wait for this element and then execute this 1 time.

```
    if(  $(".slide-1").is(":visible") == true )
{  
     var test5 = jQuery("h1,p",".feature-box-text");
     test5.wrapInner('<span></span>');
}
if(  $(".slide-2").is(":visible") == true )
{  
     var test6 = jQuery("h1,p",".feature-box-text");
     test6.wrapInner('<span></span>');      
}
if(  $(".slide-3").is(":visible") == true )
{  
     var test7 = jQuery("h1,p",".feature-box-text");
     test7.wrapInner('<span></span>');       
}
if(  $(".slide-4").is(":visible") == true )
{  
     var test8 = jQuery("h1,p",".rsts-active");
     test8.wrapInner('<span></span>');       
}
```

This is my last solution but i still need to wait with the "if" until the element exists or wait for this element.

How can i do that ?

Comment: Wait until element is added to the DOM or wait until it's become visible?

Comment: Any error messages from the console?

Comment: I dont know which one works or works better with visible or in the DOM. The slider ist the Rocksolid slider from. http://demo.rocksolidthemes.com/contao/tao/ there u can test it. Ive no errors in the console =)

Comment: your first if statement is without close bracket in actual code or its just typing mistake here?

Comment: just a mistake sorry Blu Angel, it works but only on the first slide, i tried alot but it only affects the first slide because the other slides arent visible for jquerry i think.

Comment: Are you want to wrap some elements with span tag? If so, you don't need any is(":visible")... Just remove them, and text would be wrapped even in hidden slides, it is OK

Comment: Max Zuber ive tried that but not with this code, but this didnt worked for me. ill double check that

Comment: Tried: `if(  $(".slide-1") == true )` dont work, also tried `var test = jQuery('#vor_slider h1');` second one is for the complete slider elements, dont work on other slides

Comment: See my full answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there some common class for each slider? Suppose it is a "ce_rsce_tao_feature_box". Add into $(document).ready() the following code:

```
$('.ce_rsce_tao_feature_box').each(function() {
  var current_slider = $(this);
  current_slider.find('h1,p').wrapInner('<span></span>');
  current_slider.find('.feature-box-text').wrapInner('<span></span>');
});
```

Comment: thank you for your work, but this too dont works for me, maybe im too stupid but if you watch in sript.js on http://goo.gl/r6pbl0 last lines there you see my code

Comment: There is an error for livequery, you should not try all answers together. Place my code in $(document).ready() section after slider plugin initialization, maybe this classname set by the plugin.

Comment: worked - but only when it is in the slider template =) thank you !

Answer (score 0):

If you want to notification once your DOM change, you should take a look at [Live Query](http://plugins.jquery.com/livequery/).  This jquery plugin will trigger a callback when a DOM element will match your selector:

```
$('.slide2:visible').livequery(function() {
    alert("My slide 2 is now visible!");
});
```

Comment: `$('.slide2:visible').livequery(function() {
    alert("My slide 2 is now visible!");
});` Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': '.slide2:visible' is not a valid selector.    when im trying without the :visible `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'livequery' of null`